# Setting specific file upload mime types in MURA CMS?

Tags: coldfusion, mura

Adobe ColdFusion 11/MURA CMS 6

I would like to know where I can set the "accept" attribute of `<CFFILE ACTION="upload">` in MURA CMS. I have created a class extension attribute of type "user" and am using a 'file' form field. 
I would like users to be only able to upload '.pdf' & '.doc' file formats.

For me, just relying on a bit of JavaScript regex as validation, is not good enough, and opens up the server to potential risk.

I would also like to enforce the "strict" attribute in `<CFFILE ACTION="upload">`, because this actually checks the file type signature and not just the extension.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are wanting to set these restrictions. Mura has some options in it's configuration file 'settings.ini.cfm' that you may want to look at. Namely `AllowedExtensions`, `FMAllowedExtensions`, `FMPublicAllowedExtensions`, and `AllowedMimeTypes`. You should be able to Google for references.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. I don't actually have any of these settings in my 'settings.ini.cfm', but maybe they were just missing? I will try AllowedExtensions & AllowedMimeTypes, to start with. I don't know what the prefix 'FM' means, so I will leave these ones out? I am upvoting this...